Unable to add custom endpoint for superset
I'm trying to add an endpoint(defined on custom_config.py), but it is not accessible
class CustomAuthUserView(BaseSecurityManager.authremoteuserview):
    @expose('/checkSession', methods=['GET',])
    def check_session(self):
        logger.info('Checking session validity...')

I'm running superset using helm upgrade(kubernetes pod).
When trying to access http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/check_session
it's returning 404.
